# How to filter and log one instance of a line

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a log file with thousands of lines. I can filter it down to several hundreds of lines.  Most of the lines are repeated lines with the same info and I would like only one instance of those repeated lines to be displayed.

```
cat file.log | grep "plugin time out"

hostA plugin time out
hostA plugin time out
hostA plugin time out
hostB plugin time out
hostB plugin time out
hostC plugin time out
```

How do I get only this output:

```
hostA plugin time out
hostB plugin time out
hostC plugin time out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add pipe to uniq

```
cat file.log | grep "plugin time out" |uniq
```

Comment: is uniq a standard tool? I only ask because some systems I would like to run this on are circa RHEL4

Comment: It works for what I need and it was on the box already.  I also used --skip-fields=N characters to skip the first few characters of the lines I didn't want.  Thank you for showing me this command!

Answer (score 1):

Some comments and suggestions

- Avoid [Useless Use Of Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#UUOC_.28Useless_Use_Of_Cat.29). Many commands can directly accept filename as input and if not, use re-direction. For ex: `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' < ip.txt` or `< ip.txt tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'`
- Use single quotes to avoid shell interpretation. See [mywiki.wooledge - Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

solution using `awk`

```
$ awk '/plugin time out/ && !seen[$1]++' file.log
hostA plugin time out
hostB plugin time out
hostC plugin time out
```

- `/plugin time out/` is like `grep` usage. Filter lines matching `plugin time out`
- `!seen[$1]++` to filter only unique lines based on first column of such lines (by default `awk` splits input lines on white-spaces and the fields are accessible via `$1`, `$2`, etc)

  - `seen` is associative array with first field as keys. Default value in numeric context is `0`. So `!seen[$1]` will be true only for first occurrence

Comment: That's a great solution too. I don't have enough experience with sed/awk so this will help and it's more compact than using 3 different commands.